# Run a macro automatically every minutes

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning
Basically I am importing index data from the web (abcbourse.com) and I make it refresh every minutes.

I created a macro in order to recorder historical values of each index (starting with the CAC40 as you can see in the screenshot, with new values going on column E every minute (each time the data is automatically refreshed)
Here is my macro, working well (see Column E of the screenshot):

```
Sub Historical_Index()
    Dim LastLRow As Integer, CurrentIndexValue As Single

    LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    CurrentIndexValue = Range("B1")

    Do
        If Not IsEmpty(CurrentIndexValue) = True Then
            Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = CurrentIndexValue
            Exit Do
        End If   
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

My problem is, I want this macro to run every time the data is refreshed. I initially used a

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Historical_Index
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And this is indeed calling my macro but only if I change B2 manually. If I wait for the data to be refreshed automatically my macro is not called (even though the data has changed).

I would like to know what to do in order to automate this process, I need your help.

Thanks in advance
Ps: I don’t know if it matters, but my macro is saved in *VBAProject(“this document”)* > Sheet2 (Sheet2)

Comment: `QueryTable` has an `AfterRefresh` event, documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-afterrefresh-event-excel) - You can create a class to capture that event and use a handler to trigger your macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below for the range `B1:B8:`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
  If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B1:B8")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Historical_Index
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

or if you want to check only `B2`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
  If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Historical_Index
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nikolaos Polygenis > I tried your code for B1 only, and this seems to be working.

Comment: I am new in this website, do you mean I need to rate your answer? If so, how can I do?

Comment: That's what I did, it displays a "1", and one second after a "0" instead